# Echoing double "

Tags: php

How can i echo " i mean if i want to show: "Patrik", i would do:

```
<?php echo " "Patrik" "; ?>
```

but as you know you cant do this

Comment: See http://pt.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape double quotes with `\` when full string itself is in double quotes:

```
<?php echo " \"Patrik\" "; ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo ' "Patrik" '; ?>
```

**More Info:**

- [PHP: Double quotes vs Single quotes](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-3750.html)
- http://pt.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo '"Patrik"'; ?> or.. <?php echo "\"Patrik\""; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
 echo " \"Patrik\" ";
// or
 echo '"Patrick"';
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

if it's HTML or XML, you can use `&#34;` as substitute for the double-quote.